# Docker prod and dev environment difference

Tags: docker

Microservices have one db per service. On dev we use docker-compose to bring up whole environment, web, php, mysql, but what is good way to do this on production? when load increases we have to create **several copies** of application on different servers but they all should use **same database**,
whats best way to do this?

==========================

1 app and 1 db on dev (using docker-compose), 10 app and 1 db on prod. Since db contains all the data, that must be shared between copies of application

I know about Kubernetes and Docker swarm, but I am asking about general approach of separating db from application on prod, while keeping it together on dev

Comment: The usual way is to use some higher-level orchestration technology that will allow you to scale the server and database pods separately, but "recommend a tool" isn't really on-topic for SO.

Comment: Please update your question with an example of your compose file.

Answer (score 0):

Under compose v3 files, you can specify a deploy, replicas value, which will replicate your services according to the properties and parameters you set. These can each talk to the single replica of your db by name. The overlay network they are attached to will route requests to the database by dns. For example:

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  api1:
    image: api1:latest
    deploy:
      replicas: 3
   api2:
     image: api2:latest
     deploy:
       replicas: 6
   redis:
     image: redis
     deploy:
       replicas: 1

   ... etc.
```

Now, if each service simply connects to a host called 'redis' (the service name) which is resolved by dns on the given network (which I haven't shown) on the default port. Note that it's not necessary to 'link' the services to the db -- a lot of examples do that but it's a deprecated practice. Also, you don't have to expose any ports, because the network traffic is internal you don't require ingress from a client external to the network.

Comment: docker orchestration and management tools like K8s and Swarm are good options. Couple things to mention in addition to the answer from 'Engineer Dollery' above; you can use also just use IAAS in AWS, GCP, & Azure etc. instead of the PAAS options. Also you might not need docker EE straight away, which requires a license fee for each host in the swarm - CE might be OK depending on your requirements.

You should also have a look at Portainer.io as a free tool for managing your docker environment..

Comment: I am asking about database, I know about kubernets and docker swarm, the question is if you duplicate application which has database inside docker-compose, you will have duplicated database and you don't need it. In this case some decision have to be taken and I am asking about the best way

Comment: For example, the Compose file in this answer has only one replica of the `redis` (in-memory database) container, but 3 and 6 replicas of the `api` containers (which presumably don't include databases).